# What's the need for voltage detector ICs for batteries/supercapacitors?

Tags: supercapacitor

I came across some voltage detector ICs (like the KA75XX) that are designed to detect battery voltage.

I am wondering what's the need for the these when using it with a microcontroller like an Arduino? Since the Arduino has analog inputs, can't you just wire the battery directly to those pins and do an analogRead() with the Arduino? (with an internal pull-up enabled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reliability: When you need to detect a supply voltage drop and need to turn of e.g. all the machinery, then you don't want to rely on a microcontroller which might already be misbehaving because of undervoltage.

Also, especially the KA75XX are from a time where microcontrollers even lacked basic things like brownout detection and couldn't reset themselves. That's why they needed external circuitry to do that.